# SPARQL: UNION drops values, OPTIONAL needs separate variables

Tags: sparql, union, group-concat, wikidata

How can I get all the labels and aliases for a given country, in both English and the official language(s) of this country, as a single column, from wikidata?

I initially tried the following but `UNION` seems to drop the labels in the official language:

[Attempt #1](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%20%20%3Fcountry_iso%0A%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%28%3Flabel%29%20%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Flabels%29%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%20wd%3AQ878%20%7D%20%23%20FOR%20TESTING%20PURPOSES%2C%20TO%20REMOVE%20ONCE%20ISSUE%20RESOLVED.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20country%20%20sovereign%20state%20%20unincorporated%20territory%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fany_kind_of_country%20%7B%20wd%3AQ6256%20wd%3AQ3624078%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ783733%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fany_kind_of_country%20.%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20true%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fcountry_iso%20%3B%20%23%20ISO%203166-1%20alpha-2%20code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP37%20%3Fofficial_lang%20.%0A%20%20%3Fofficial_lang%20wdt%3AP424%20%3Fwm_lang_code%20.%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%3Fwm_lang_code%29%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%3Fwm_lang_code%29%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry_iso%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcountry_iso):

```
SELECT
  ?country_iso
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?label) ; separator = ", ") AS ?labels)
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?country { wd:Q878 } # FOR TESTING PURPOSES, TO REMOVE ONCE ISSUE RESOLVED.
                              # country  sovereign state  unincorporated territory
  VALUES ?any_kind_of_country { wd:Q6256 wd:Q3624078      wd:Q783733 }
  ?country wdt:P31 ?any_kind_of_country . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?country wdt:P297 ?country_iso ; # ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code
           wdt:P37 ?official_lang .
  ?official_lang wdt:P424 ?wm_lang_code .
  { ?country rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en") }
  UNION
  { ?country rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = ?wm_lang_code) }
  UNION
  { ?country skos:altLabel ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en") }
  UNION
  { ?country skos:altLabel ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = ?wm_lang_code) }
}
GROUP BY ?country_iso
ORDER BY ?country_iso
```

```markdown
| country_iso | labels                                                                                                           |
|-------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| AE          | United Arab Emirates, ae, , Emirates, the Emirates, the U.A.E., the UAE, the United Arab Emirates, U.A.E., UAE |
```

If I use two separate variables `?label` and `?altLabel` and `OPTIONAL`, then I seem to get all the labels and aliases, but:

- a. I'm not convinced `||` is right there, although it *seems* to produce the right results,
- b. two columns (`?labels` and `?altLabels`) isn't ideal in my case. (And if I only use one, then only `rdfs:label` gets returned.)

[Attempt #2](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%20%20%3Fcountry_iso%0A%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%28%3Flabel%29%20%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Flabels%29%0A%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%28%3FaltLabel%29%20%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3FaltLabels%29%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%20wd%3AQ878%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20country%20%20sovereign%20state%20%20unincorporated%20territory%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fany_kind_of_country%20%7B%20wd%3AQ6256%20wd%3AQ3624078%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ783733%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fany_kind_of_country%20.%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20true%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fcountry_iso%20%3B%20%23%20ISO%203166-1%20alpha-2%20code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP37%20%3Fofficial_lang%20.%0A%20%20%3Fofficial_lang%20wdt%3AP424%20%3Fwm_lang_code%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%7C%7C%20LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%3Fwm_lang_code%29%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3FaltLabel%20.%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3FaltLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%7C%7C%20LANG%28%3FaltLabel%29%20%3D%20%3Fwm_lang_code%29%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry_iso%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcountry_iso)

```
SELECT
  ?country_iso
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?label) ; separator = ", ") AS ?labels)
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?altLabel) ; separator = ", ") AS ?altLabels)
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?country { wd:Q878 }
                              # country  sovereign state  unincorporated territory
  VALUES ?any_kind_of_country { wd:Q6256 wd:Q3624078      wd:Q783733 }
  ?country wdt:P31 ?any_kind_of_country . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?country wdt:P297 ?country_iso ; # ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code
           wdt:P37 ?official_lang .
  ?official_lang wdt:P424 ?wm_lang_code .
  OPTIONAL { ?country rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en" || LANG(?label) = ?wm_lang_code) }
  OPTIONAL { ?country skos:altLabel ?altLabel . FILTER(LANG(?altLabel) = "en" || LANG(?altLabel) = ?wm_lang_code) }
}
GROUP BY ?country_iso
ORDER BY ?country_iso
```

```markdown
| country_iso | labels                                         | altLabels                                                                                                                           |
|-------------|------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| AE          | United Arab Emirates, الإمارات العربية المتحدة | الإمارات, دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة, ae, , Emirates, the Emirates, the U.A.E., the UAE, the United Arab Emirates, U.A.E., UAE |
```

What am I missing?  Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Disclaimer: relatively new to SPARQL (or rather, very rusty).

Comment: I wonder if it could be an issue with your query looking for the UAE and Arabic being right-to-left and English left-to-right.
Your query seems to work just fine for other countries, see https://w.wiki/5SWw

Comment: The same seems to happen to Israel, where the official language is Hebrew, also read right-to-left: https://w.wiki/5SXH
and https://w.wiki/5SXK

Comment: It's an issue with the filter eval in the UNION it looks like.

Comment: MY suggestion, use a property path: `?country rdfs:label|skos:altLabel ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en" || LANG(?label) = ?wm_lang_code)` like https://w.wiki/5SXg

Comment: @ValerioCocchi, thanks for looking into this.  If I run the 2nd query (using `OPTIONAL`) against France, Russia, and the USA, like you did with the 1st query, I do get more results even for these languages. See also: https://w.wiki/5Sq9
Therefore, it seems like the issue is elsewhere. 

Comment: @UninformedUser, thanks for looking into this.   It does seem to do the trick! Thank you so much! https://w.wiki/5SqF Would you the reason?  I'd like to understand why.

Comment: @UninformedUser, I've posted a solution for posterity, but unsure how to attribute you the reward. If you'd like to post a solution with the same content, I'll happily delete mine and mark yours as accepted. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @UninformedUser (see comments) I was able to come up with [this query](https://w.wiki/5SxH), yielding 206 results:

```
SELECT
  ?country_iso
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?label) ; separator = " | ") AS ?labels)
WHERE
{
                              # country  sovereign state  unincorporated territory
  VALUES ?any_kind_of_country { wd:Q6256 wd:Q3624078      wd:Q783733 }
  ?country wdt:P31 ?any_kind_of_country . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?country wdt:P297 ?country_iso ; # ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code
           wdt:P37 ?official_lang .
  ?official_lang wdt:P424 ?wm_lang_code .
  ?country rdfs:label|skos:altLabel ?label . FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en" || LANG(?label) = ?wm_lang_code)
}
GROUP BY ?country_iso
ORDER BY ?country_iso
```

P.S.: An extension of this work, also fetching emoji flags is [that query](https://w.wiki/5UEq).